# Awk: how to replace text within block, but print everything else

Tags: awk, replace

I am able to replace the string **AllowOverride None** with **AllowOverride All** in the block , but I am only able to print the block of text that matches.

How do I print the text before and after the match?

```
awk '
/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/, /<\/Directory>/ {
  sub(/AllowOverride None/,"AllowOverride All")
  print
}
' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just perform the substitution without printing in the first clause, and then add a second clause to print every line. Like this:

```
awk '
/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/, /<\/Directory>/ {
    sub(/AllowOverride None/, "AllowOverride All");
}
{
    print;
}
' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

I did a quickie test of this, and I believe it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `next` after your existing `print` and add this after your existing closing curly brace:

```
{print}
```